# FabricJS 2 - Having a canvas both read and write to a redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, fabricjs

I am currently making a react application using fabric.js 2, and I've rather quickly run into a snag. I want to serialize a fabric canvas into a redux store, and also load its state back into the canvas from said store. This is easier said than done!

## What I'm currently doing

- Anytime an action occurs on the canvas that alters state in a 'interaction complete' sort of way (key:up, object:modified, etc) I send the active selection and the full canvas.toJSON() into the redux store.
- The connected canvas element's render function includes a call that loadfromJSON's the current redux state (it also sets the active selected object). Note that this means that when I complete an interaction I perform both a toJSON and loadfromJSON on the canvas.

In this way I have a canvas that can be rewound via redux, and all that is fine and good. This is especially useful to me because it allows for easy undo and redo.

I worry about this, especially when it comes to large images with complex filters, as I can see that initFilters is being run on images on every modification now. Anyone else have any ideas, maybe to send an immutable copy of some kind of internal fabric state there instead of the toJSON fromJSON dance?